# Build fail with (Google I/O Android App 2017)

Tags: android, googleio

Error log:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
/Users/samuelyang/AndroidStudioProjects/iosched-master/server/build/generated-source/endpoints/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/rpc/cms/Cms.java:346: 
error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@override
^
```

---

How do i build it?

The Error is occurred a file named Cms.java, and the code snipe of Cms.java as below:

```
@Override
public Builder setBatchPath(String batchPath) {
  return (Builder) super.setBatchPath(batchPath);
}
```

Every time i comment all these error code snipe and build the project, all these code will be auto-gen ,i don't know how to handle this...
Could anyone help me? thanks...

[Download Google I/O 2017 Android App here](https://github.com/google/iosched)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with other project. 
Try to change google-api-client libraries from 1.22.0 to 1.23.0 in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'     
compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.23.0'
```